# JQueryUI draggable plus -webkit-overflow-scrolling hides dragging elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, jquery-ui

I have a scrolling div that scrolls beautifully on iPad2 using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;`.

Inside, I have draggable elements using `JQueryUI.draggable` and `TouchPunch` to enable dragging via touch on mobile.

I'm so close to having it work perfectly, but I've found an issue. With divs set up like this, my `JQueryUI draggable helper` object won't float over-top everything else. With `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` off, it floats properly, but scrolls choppy.

Is there a way to have the best of both worlds?

[Here's a JSBin, please view using an iPad or iPhone to see the problem!](http://jsbin.com/aPaHiVi/6)

[Here's an EDITing view of the JSBin](http://jsbin.com/aPaHiVi/6/edit)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I just needed to make the draggable append the helper to body

`$(element).draggable({appendTo: 'body'});`

[This JS Bin still works for posterity. Try this on iPad](http://jsbin.com/aPaHiVi/6)

[Here's the code editing version](http://jsbin.com/aPaHiVi/6/edit)