# JQueryUI - Draggable inside scrollable div hides dragging element

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Working with JQuery UI-Draggable divs inside a container with fixed height and scrollable y-axis. The `overflow-y: scroll`-rule hides the draggable elements whenever they're dragged outside the container.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DendrilT/a68ytmbw/2/) with `overflow-y: scroll`

<s>jsFiddle</s> with no `overflow`

---

I've seen [Prodikl's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20988243/6025684), which includes a helper-clone appended to the document body. I'd like to find a solution that doesn't utilize a helper-clone. I need to visualize that the actual div is moving.

<s>jsFiddle</s> of Prodikl's solution to my problem, to confirm that it does indeed work.

---

What I've tried:

- setting the `z-index` of both the draggable divs to `99999`
- setting the `overflow-x` of both the draggable to `visible`, `auto`, `initial`, `inherit`
- setting `containment`-option to `.master-container` and higher
- setting `stack`-option to `.master-container` and higher
- setting `zIndex`-option to `99999`
- all of the options above simultaneously

---

Edit:

removed 3 links because I lack reputation to post more than 2 links.

If you're looking for the jsFiddles, they're on the same URL with ending ID `a68ytmbw/4/` and `a68ytmbw/3/`, instead of `a68ytmbw/2/`, respectively. **Please let me know if I'm breaking the rules by posting the excess references to the jsFiddle.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a derivation from answer by @Twisty

Using `helper` and hiding the parent while dragging.

```
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    start: (event, ui) => {
      $(event.target).addClass('hidden-but-present');
    },
    stop: (event, ui) => {
      $(event.target).removeClass('hidden-but-present');
    },
    revert: true,
    helper: function(e) {
      var c = $("<div>", {
        class: "draggable text-style",
        style: "width: 200px; height: 90px;"
      }).html($(e.target).text());
      return c;
    }
  });

  $(".dropzone").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $("#dragResult").text("Dropped box #" + ui.draggable.text() + " in dropzone");
    }
  });
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/hsdzs4jv/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `helper` as a function, and generate a new element that is not appended to the div, thus it's not bound by overflow issue.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: true,
    helper: function(e) {
      var c = $("<div>", {
        class: "draggable text-style",
        style: "width: 200px; height: 90px;"
      }).html($(e.target).text());
      return c;
    }
  });

  $(".dropzone").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $("#dragResult").text("Dropped box #" + ui.helper.text() + " in dropzone");
    }
  });
});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/a68ytmbw/7/

Comment: Late response, my apologies. I had to put the project on hold. Your solution utilizes helpers, which is against my specification. I would like to see the actual <div> move. Revisited the issue, couldn't find a solution.

Comment: @Dendril it's not a `clone` and I think I see what you are driving at. You want the target item to appear like it is being moved (no longer in the list) and become dropped on the work area. Will see if we can can use `appendTo` and `.position()` to create this effect.

Comment: That's correct. One solution is to hide the origin element when the helper is spawned. Another is to remove the origin element from the container and append it to a higher container. Both of those seemed too clunky as a sustainable solution.